# Виден ли другим участникам сообщества удаленный ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, инструменты-модератора

Виден ли другим участникам сообщества удаленный ответ?

Comment: И чтобы два раза не вставать: и ответы и вопросы видны. Вы спрашиваете только про удалённые ответы, но и Юрий и Suvitruf подчёркнуто пишут о "удалённых сообщениях". А удалённые  комментарии ЕМНИП видны только модераторам.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, виден. Все у кого есть 10000 репутации [могут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) просматривать удалённые сообщения.

Если у вас туда попала важная информация, например, пароль, то ничего с этим сделать нельзя. Если только не позвать 2 модераторов. Один из них может отредактировать правку сообщения, а второй - эту правку подтвердить. После этого в истории правок удалённого сообщения важной информации никто не увидит.

Comment: спасибо.. буду бдительнее

Answer (score 7):

Если есть 10к репутации, то у вас открываются [инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). После этого можно просматривать удалённые сообщения:

1. Если есть прямая ссылка.
2. В [инструментах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools) недавно удалённые можно найти.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]